# The data is not separated by its id, the last data that arrives is replacing everything

Tags: angular

if someone could help me, I have the following problem, I am bringing a list of users by project id, the problem is that when I bring it it always throws the options of the last one but not the option in which I am, all the values ​​come from each option by id but always the one that arrives last will crush the other option if someone can help me please

```
        <mat-form-field class="flex-auto">
            <mat-label>MIEMBROS</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="userId" #labelSelect="matSelect" multiple>

                <mat-option (click)="createCustomer()" *ngFor="let user of customersUsuarios;" [value]="user.id">
                    {{ user.nombres }} {{ user.apellidos}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>

        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="sm:ml-6 flex-auto" style="display: none;">
            <mat-label>ID DEL PROYECTO</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="projectId" disabled readonly [(ngModel)]="defaults.id" matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

TS

```
        this.API.getProjects()
  .subscribe((data: CustomerProyecto[]) => {
    this.customersProyecto = data;
    data.forEach((element, i) => {
      this.API.getDataUsuariosNoRegistrados(element.id)

        .subscribe((data2: any) => {

          this.customersUsuarios = data2
          console.log("id del elemento ", element.id)

          console.log("datos de los usuarios ", data2)

        });
    });


  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Move `this.customersUsuarios` before calling the API (if it's not assigned as array beforehand) like this

```js
this.customersUsuarios = []
this.API.getDataUsuariosNoRegistrados(element.id)
...
```

and instead of assigning `data2` directly to `this.customersUsuarios`, push the data into the array (considering `data2` is coming as an array)

```js
// this.customersUsuarios = data2

// pushing data from `data2` inside array of `customersUsuarios`
// so, all the data can be collected instead of the last one only
this.customersUsuarios.push(...data2)
```

**Details**: We are assigning the data coming inside `data2` directly to `this.customersUsuarios` so, whenever new data comes via `data2` it replaces the data already present inside the array from previous API calls

So, instead of assigning it like this. We need to accumulate all the responses coming inside the `data2` one by one, starting with an empty array (consider this a container) before calling any API, then combining/merging responses by pushing the new `data2` into that array for each element (merging the content already inside the container with the new one for each element)

You can use any merging technique examples of which are given below

```js
// As mentioned previously, it adds the data directly into `this.customersUsuarios`
this.customersUsuarios.push(...data2)

/** 
 * OR 
 * 
 * concat two arrays (just like old days)
 * here we are assigning it because `concat` returns 
 * a new merged array and does not alter the array in question
 */
this.customersUsuarios = this.customersUsuarios.concat(data2)

// Another concat approach, same reason whichever you find easy to reason about
this.customersUsuarios = [].concat(this.customersUsuarios, data2);
```

This is how `this.customersUsuarios` will yield all the responses coming inside `data2` for each API call

This answer is based on what I can understand from this (let me know if I am wrong here I will try to solve that as well)